# Borda em Imagem dentro de Select Radio após escolher uma opção

Tags: javascript, css

Eu tenho uma loja virtual no qual ela gera o seguinte HTML de um `select` que tem imagem dentro dele. Eu gostaria de esconder o `input` (bolinha do select radio) e exibir apenas uma borda na imagem que for selecionada que irá corresponder ao `select` selecionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Importante

Os `input` radio serão gerados automaticamente na loja com um `html` idêntico a este, a diferença será que em cada produto o nome do `input` será diferente, nestes meus exemplos tem os nomes `option[238]` e `option[239]`. Porém a loja irá gerar mais outros, como `option[240]`, `option[241]` ...

Uma resposta abaixo do @Mateus Veloso me ajudou se em meu código tivesse apenas um `input radio` com suas devidas opções. Porém meu caso terá mais de `input radio`. Com isso a solução dele deixa apenas o último `input radio` marcado com a borda e os outros `inputs` com suas devidas opções não fica visível qual foi a escolha do usuário. [Veja aqui a demonstração.](https://jsfiddle.net/wendell_chrys/nwp0ckym/)

Os `input`serão de seleção única, porém terão mais de um `inpupt radio` cada um com suas opções podendo somente uma delas ser marcada. Exemplo, existe o `input radio` "Cor Palmilha" com suas respectivas cores (somente uma delas pode ser marcada), depois tem "Cor Solado" com suas respectivas cores e assim vai. O fato é que eles não terão um nome definido, serão gerados automaticamente. No link de exemplo que coloquei, o "Cor Palmilha" tem `name="option[238]"` mas poderá ter outro nome.

### Aqui você consegue ver o código em funcionamento:

```css
#product .radio {
    display: inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
}
.radio {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.radio input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 4px\9;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
#product .radio label {
    display: block;
    background: none;
    color: #111111;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
 font-size:0;
}
#product .radio label input {
 margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="product">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label">Cor Palmilha</label>
        <div id="input-option238">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[238]" value="56">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/krdm2veer/cor-produto-cinza.jpg" alt="Cinza" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[238]" value="55">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/da4ennovn/cor-produto-verde.jpg" alt="Verde" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label">Cor Solado</label>
        <div id="input-option239">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[239]" value="66">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/krdm2veer/cor-produto-cinza.jpg" alt="Cinza" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[239]" value="67">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/da4ennovn/cor-produto-verde.jpg" alt="Verde" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: e ao selecionar a cor escura qual seria a cor da borda?

Comment: A cor da borda seria a mesma independente da seleção.

Comment: Ok, deixa ver se eu entendi. Existirão mais de um input para serem marcados é isso? Se eu quiser selecionar 5 cores eu tenho que conseguir fazer isso. Estou certo?

Comment: Não, eles serão de seleção única, porém terão mais de um `inpupt radio` cada um com suas opções podendo somente uma delas ser marcada. Exemplo, existe o `input radio` "Cor Palmilha" com suas respectivas cores (somente uma delas pode ser marcada), depois tem "Cor Solado" com suas respectivas cores e assim vai. O fato é que eles não terão um nome definido, serão gerados automaticamente. No link de exemplo que coloquei, o "Cor Palmilha" tem `name="option[238]" ` mas poderá ter outro nome.

Comment: Não há a possibilidade de alteração do formato de HTML do codigo? Consegui soluciona-lo de maneira bem simples apenas com o css. :/

Comment: @PauloMartins poste sua resposta então, assim vejo se tem como fazer alguma adaptação para a estrutura da loja.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Podes fazer isso só com CSS:

```
#product .radio label input + img {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
#product .radio label input:checked+img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Isso muda a cor da borda da imagem quando o `input` estiver selecionado.
Escondi também o input com `opacity: 0;` para não estar visivel

```css
#product .radio {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.radio {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.radio input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px\9;
  margin-left: -20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#product .radio label {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  color: #111111;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

#product .radio label input + img {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
#product .radio label input:checked+img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="product">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label">Cor Palmilha</label>
    <div id="input-option238">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[238]" value="56">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/krdm2veer/cor-produto-cinza.jpg" alt="Cinza" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[238]" value="55">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/da4ennovn/cor-produto-verde.jpg" alt="Verde" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label">Cor Solado</label>
    <div id="input-option239">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[239]" value="66">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/krdm2veer/cor-produto-cinza.jpg" alt="Cinza" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[239]" value="67">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/da4ennovn/cor-produto-verde.jpg" alt="Verde" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Exemplo funcional

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type=radio]').on('change',function(){
    $('.radio').css('border','');
    $(this).parent().parent().css('border','2px solid red');
  });
});
```

```css
#product .radio {
    display: inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
}
.radio {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.radio input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 4px\9;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
#product .radio label {
    display: block;
    background: none;
    color: #111111;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
 font-size:0;
}
#product .radio label input {
 margin-left: 15px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label">Cor Palmilha</label>
        <div id="input-option238">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[238]" value="56">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/krdm2veer/cor-produto-cinza.jpg" alt="Cinza" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[238]" value="55">
                        <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/da4ennovn/cor-produto-verde.jpg" alt="Verde" class="img-thumbnail"> 
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oi, seu código funcionou pra mim quando estava com apenas uma opção de input radio. Mas quando inseri outras opções que necessitariam de mais campos input radio, a borda estava sendo visível apenas no último radio visitado. Eu atualizei meu código html e [coloquei aqui o exemplo para entender melhor](https://jsfiddle.net/wendell_chrys/nwp0ckym/).

Comment: Penso que esteja dando errado no seu exemplo porque ele escuta o evento de mudança de todos `'input[type=radio]'` e quando o evento é disparado em um, independente de qual seja, ele irá mudar. Vc deveria selecionar por nome, por exemplo. Dessa forma quando selecionasse uma cor da palmilha, não iria afetar os radios da cor do solado.

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta @Wendell, o Fiddle que você colocou não tem erro

Comment: @MateusVeloso note que no [meu Fiddle aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/wendell_chrys/nwp0ckym/), ao escolher a cor da Palmilha e logo após escolher a cor do solado, fica marcado somente a cor do solado, sendo que a cor da palmilha escolhida também deveria ficar marcada.

Comment: @HamurabiAraujo você consegue criar uma resposta com esta sua solução? Lembrando que os `radios` são gerados automaticamente na loja e em cada produto o nome é diferente, no exemplo que coloquei é `option[238]` mas esse número no final do nome vai aumentando sempre.

Comment: Resolvido, setei uma class para cada 'bloco' de radios, de uma olhada no código : https://jsfiddle.net/a1k5jen1/

Answer (score 0):

É possivel solucionar o problema apenas com o CSS mesmo, caso o HTML possua uma tag label referenciando o node de radio.

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
input {
    visibility:hidden;
}
label {
    display: block;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d2d2d2;
    background: #c32121;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
input:checked + label {
    border-color: #c32121;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="product" value="p1" id="p1">
  <label for='p1'></label>
  <input type="radio" name="product" value="p2" id="p2">
  <label for='p2'></label>
  <input type="radio" name="product" value="p3" id="p3">
  <label for='p3'></label>
</form>
```

Uma das vantagens dessa solução é ser "nativamente" executada pelo navegador (por não ter JS), assim o codigo será executado mais rápido junto com todos os outros conteudos de CSS.